# Javascript convert query string to JSON using jQuery and back to query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, query-string

Hope you will find following function useful for converting query string into json object

```
var queryStringToJSON = function (url) {
    if (url === '')
        return '';
    var pairs = (url || location.search).slice(1).split('&');
    var result = {};
    for (var idx in pairs) {
        var pair = pairs[idx].split('=');
        if (!!pair[0])
            result[pair[0].toLowerCase()] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Usage:**

To get current windows query string

```
var result = queryStringToJSON() // without any parameter
```

To get json from custom query string:

```
var result = queryStringToJSON('?name=prem&age=30&HEIGHT=5.8')
```

**output:** `{name:"prem", age:"30", height:"5.8"} //All keys are converted into small letters`

To convert it back to url you can use *jQuery param* method

```
$.param(result)
```

To manipulate your query string you can simple use standard object manipulation in JavaScript and use $.param method again

```
result.age=35;
delete result['name'];
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: he just posted his useful function to help others... so no question here...

Comment: Then why did I find this in "questions" section?

Comment: This does not seem to be working with array's: eg: ?=name=Tom&name=Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Working, but if you used `url || location.search` then you should remove `if(url === '') return ''` or it should be like,

```
var queryStringToJSON = function (url) {
    url = url || location.search;// url or location.search
    if (url === '')
        return '';// return if url and location.search not found
    // your remainig code
}
```

Comment: Understood but this is a special check. '' is special falsy value in string manipulation. So I just want a check if falsy value is empty string just return as it is.

Comment: Then you should not use `location.search` in line `var pairs = (url || location.search).slice(1).split('&');`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively...  Instead of:

```
for (var idx in pairs) {
    var pair = pairs[idx].split('=');
    if (!!pair[0])
        result[pair[0].toLowerCase()] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
}
```

Try:

```
result = pairs.reduce(function(a,b) {
     var pair = b.split("=");
     a[pair[0].toLowerCase()] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
     return a;
},{});
```

Works the same but uses `reduce()` which being a native javascript function, is probably faster.

Comment: You need a polyfill for reduce if you need to support IE8 or lower. Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill