# Jquery .ajax() SyntaxError: Unexpected token N

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, submit, form-submit

I have the following code which displays a form and is supposed to submit the form data via Jquery .ajax() to be saved into a MySQL database. On submitting the form, I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token N`. What does this mean and how can I resolve it?

HTML:

```
<form class="well" id="jquery-submit-ajax" name="jquery-submit-ajax" method="post" action="ajax.php">
  <div class="floatleft">
<input type="text" class="span7" name="yourName" placeholder="Your Name">
  </div>
  <div class="floatleft">
<input type="text" class="span7" name="yourNumber" placeholder="Your Number">
  </div>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Schedule">
<br /><br />
<div class="alert alert-success hide">
    <p>Form successfully submitted! The data sent is below:</p>
    <div id="success-output" class="prettyprint"></div>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-error hide">
    <p>Error below:</p>
    <div id="error-output" class="prettyprint"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
$("#jquery-submit-ajax").submit(function(e) {
    var postData = $(e.target).serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: postData,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend:function(){
        $('.alert-error,.alert-success').hide();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        $('.alert-error').fadeIn();
        $('#error-output').html(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('.alert-success').fadeIn();
        $('#success-output').html(data);
    }
});
return false;
});
</script>
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$yourName        = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['yourName']));
$yourNumber      = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['yourNumber']));

$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (name, number)
VALUES ('$yourName', '$yourNumber')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is a NaN being passed in the JSON. NaN is unsupported in JSON. Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate the json data passed via postData.

Comment: Thank you, that appears to be correct. It's outputting `yourName=hkjhk&yourNumber=897897`. I'm pretty sure it should look like ` {"yourName": "hkjhk", "yourNumber": "897897" }`, but I'm not sure how to change that. Any advice?

Comment: Shud be easy to parse with some javascript..refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677832/javascript-convert-query-string-to-json-using-jquery-and-back-to-query-string